# Hessian matrix equal to zero in an open convex set.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $A$ be an open convex set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Suppose that $f:A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $f\in C^2(A)$ (two times continuous differentiable in $A$). If the hessian matrix is zero for all $\mathbf{a}\in A$, that is

$$H_{f}(\mathbf{a})=O_{2\times 2}\ \ \ \forall\mathbf{a}\in A$$

Is it true that $f$ is an affine linear function? Can I say that $f$ is:

$f(x,y)=c_1x+c_2y+k$

where $c_1,c_2,k\in\mathbb{R}$? I think it's true, because if ${H_{f}(\mathbf{a})}_{ij}=0$, then $f_{xx}(x,y)=0$ in $A$, so

$f_{x}(x,y)=c_1\implies f(x,y)=c_1x+d_1(y)$

i.e. $f_{x}(x,y)$ must be constant in $A$ and $f(x,y)$ must be the sum between $c_1x$ and a function of $y$.

The same idea can be used for $f_{yy}(x,y)$

$f_{yy}(x,y)=0 \implies f_{y}(x,y)=c_2$

So $f(x,y)=c_1x+d_1(y) \implies f_{y}(x,y)=d_1'(y)=c_2 \implies d_1(y)=c_2 y+ k$.

From here, I think I can conclude that $f(x,y)=c_1x+c_2y+k$. Right?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks right to me.